# Data transfer from Cassandra to SQL

Tags: sql-server, cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I want to export selected data from Cassandra to SQL. Anyone aware of any open source connector or any other work around for that. FYI, both are running on different servers. Cassandra is running on 3 node centos cluster where as MSSQL is on windows.

Below is my table strcuture :

```
CREATE TABLE EventsByLogDate (
  Id text,  
  impression bigint,
  detailView bigint,
  photoView bigint,
  btnSellerView bigint,
  response bigint,
  totalViews bigint,
  logdate timestamp,
  PRIMARY KEY (logdate, Id)
);
```

I want to export the data on a daily basis from Cassandra to MSSQL. So, in built copy command won't work, since it doesn't support where clauses.

Answer (score 1):

You may find using something like Spark to be advantageous here. You can use the Spark JDBC Dataframes api and the Spark Cassandra Connector for a Cassandra Dataframe api.

This would give you the flexibility to do just about anything to your data as you transform it into a form for MySql.

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html
https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector

Answer (score 0):

There is a ODBC connector for C* - http://www.simba.com/connectors/apache-cassandra-odbc. I've configured it in a way in which I was able to insert/update/delete data using SQL queries in C* tables.

Disclaimer: I haven't used it in any production environment.

But... although such possibility exists I need to ask: why such thing is required? You're trying to achieve something but it seems like a way to do that is not the most efficient one. Adding some information about what you'd like to achieve we'll be able to suggest you some possible solutions.

Answer (score -1):

Cassandra has a COPY command to do export or import data, but not the entire data of a keyspace, just the data of a table.

### Sample command(Cassandra 2.x)

> **Export**: COPY tablename TO 'source path'
> COPY user TO '/opt/cassandra/data_backup'
>
> **Import**: COPY table name FROM 'source path'
> COPY user FROM '/opt/cassandra/data_backup'

You can also specify columns

> COPY user(id, name) TO '/opt/cassandra/data_backup'

**References**:
http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/copy_r.html
http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/ways-to-move-data-tofrom-datastax-enterprise-and-cassandra

Good Luck!